Invariance of Acceleration vs Invariance of Magnitude of Acceleration and help with proof
This question is a half-rant, half-question, as I am genuinely curious as to what the standard physics view is on this question. As someone who has studied math extensively (but not physics), please forgive me if my motives for studying physics might be different from the usual physicists' motivations.
In classical Newtonian mechanics, why do people say "Acceleration is invariant between inertial frames" when what they really mean is "The MAGNITUDE of acceleration is invariant between inertial frames"?
Here is one example in Kogut's "Introduction to Relativity" (pg 2)

If we have two frames in relative motion at a constant linear velocity v, then the acceleration measurements are the same in both frames.

WRONG! The magnitude of acceleration is the same in both frames.
Here is another more egregious example from Woodhouse "Special Relativity":
Woodhouse first defines two (not necessarily inertial) reference frames $R$ and $R'$, which are related by an orthogonal+affine transformation: $$r=Hr' + T$$ where $H$ is an orthogonal matrix (rotation), $T$ is a column vector (translation), and $r$ and $r'$ are position vectors in the two frames (respectively). Both frames might be moving/rotating with respect to one another, so both H and T are actually functions of time as well is $r$ and $r'$. Then, by calculus: $$(*) \ \ddot{r} = \ddot{H}r' + 2\dot{H}\dot{r}' + H\ddot{r}' + \ddot{T} $$
Now, Woodhouse claims (with notation slightly changed):

Thus, $\ddot{r} = \ddot{r}'$ for all possible motion of the particle if and only if $\dot{H}=0$ and $\ddot{T}=0$. That is, if and only if $R'$ is moving relative to $R$ without rotation or acceleration.

But isn't $\ddot{r} = \ddot{r}'$ quite literally wrong here?
I attempted to prove the statement myself, had great trouble with the "only if" part of the "if and only if" as well:
If $\dot{H} =0$ and $\ddot{T} = 0$, then by simply substituting into (*), we get $$\ddot{r} = H \ddot{r}'$$ This is the moment I realized that $\ddot{r} = \ddot{r}'$ as stated above by the author is actually incorrect. Since $H$ is an orthogonal matrix, it preserves norms, and thus actually $||\ddot{r}|| = ||\ddot{r}'||$. (Only the magnitudes of acceleration is preserved.)
Having amended that issue, I proceeded to try to prove the converse, but have no idea how to proceed. We begin with the hypothesis that $\ddot{r} = H\ddot{r}'$. (Or perhaps we can start with the weaker assumption that $||\ddot{r}|| = ||\ddot{r}'||$). Substituting that into (*), we obtain: $$0 = \ddot{H}r' + 2\dot{H}\dot{r}' + \ddot{T} $$
How do we conclude from this that $\ddot{T} = 0$ and $\dot{H} = 0$?

Yes, physicists mean the magnitude in this context, don't get mad, remember that  language is contextual and also involves pragmatics.

You are technically correct, but you are missing the forest for the trees.
Yes, if we want to say what it is we want to say, in the rather rudimentary mathematical framework that we are using, then we have to have $H=\mathbb I$ i.e. no rotation, for the statement to be strictly true. We have to align the space axes. That is, for any relative velocities between observer frames, you have to pick any two orthogonal space axes and align them, so that only the Special Theory of Relativity's (hyperbolic) spacetime rotation is allowed. Then will we have $\ddot r=\ddot r{}^\prime$. Otherwise, you are correct that we have $\ddot r=H\ddot r{}^\prime$
However, that is a failure of the mathematics to capture what it is we want to say. When you go further on and use the concept of manifolds, we can capture in better detail what it is we want to say. In the mathematical language of manifolds, we are trying to say that the physical universe exists outside of our mathematical description of it. But to actually do any computation, it is necessary to use coördinates (charts, making up atlases), to map the spacetime regions of interest into subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ that we can then apply mathematical tools onto. In that sense, the absolute direction of the acceleration is invariant inside the Platonic ideal manifold world, whereas it is the coördinate representation that is changing, and we don't so much care about coördinate representations. The rotation is a rotation in the coördinate representation, not the underlying acceleration. That is, if we have an acceleration vector that is pointing in the direction from the Sun to Andromeda galaxy, after a rotation of everything in the universe, yes, the coördinate representation will appear to have different numerical components, but the acceleration vector will still be pointing from the Sun to Andromeda galaxy. It is this physics that we are trying to convey.
So, yes, you found us using language sloppily. However, that is a very common and standard sloppy language use, and we are trying to aim for something deeper that is actually correct.
